# Mi cdn de jquery no esta funcionando en linux Mint

Tags: javascript, jquery, linux

Actualmente tengo dos cdn en mi codigo que serian los siguientes:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script> 
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

En windows funcionaban correctamente, pero como me cambie a linux para seguir desarrollando la aplicacion, ya no quisieron funcionar correctamente, ya que mi menu no hace ninguna de las funciones que hacia en windows. Verifique que javascript estuviera habilitado.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

De echo ya puse un codigo de prueba que seria el siguiente:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){ 

 alert("SI funciona");

});
</script>
```

Pero no manda el alert, cuando se carga el documento.

Comment: Revisa en las herramientas de desarrollador (dev tools) si tienes algún error; en caso que así sea por favor compártelo.

Comment: @Gerry el dev tools esta en el navegador de MOzilla, ¿verdad?

Comment: Sí, es correcto.

Comment: @Gerry ya encontre el error, era porque tenia <script> y </script> dentro de un fucntion de .js

Comment: Súper. Te recomiendo responderte y aceptar la respuesta, o bien borrar la pregunta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ya resolvi mi error, el problema era porque tenia `<script>` y `</script>` dentro de un function de .js